# Content type structure (nested content: Gallery / Photo)

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I've been digging for some days how to organize my Drupal 7 site.
I want to build a site with multiple galleries, each one of them with multiple photos:
 - The galleries will show a cover photo, a description and thumbnails of the pictures;
 - Each photo will have a title, a description, date, will allow for comments, have tags, etc.
I want both the gallery and the photos as nodes (so I can have a page for a gallery and a page for each single photo with different layout).
So, I thought this would be the structure of the content types, where 1 gallery has multiple photos:

### **content type: GALLERY**

- description (text)
- cover (image)
- **photo_entries (unlimited | content type: PHOTO)**
- ...

### **content type: PHOTO**

- file (image)
- title (text)
- date_taken (text)
- ...

I tried a solution (like the one explained here:http://megadrupal.com/blog/creating-an-image-gallery-in-drupal-7) where I have an unlimited image field in my gallery, but I really want the photos to be nodes and this is the thing I don't know how to do.
I've been unsuccessfully trying using some modules like Views and entity reference, or even taxonomy, but I'm not sure what should be the approach to get this. 
This can be a very simple question and I'm sorry if it is, but I'm stuck...
I really appreciate if someone could give me advice and put me on the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for this using the [Node Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to create multimedia galleries where both the galleries and the gallery items are nodes (as opposed to gallery items being file fields, like [Media Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_gallery)).